# Convert an MP3 from 48000 to 44100 Hz?

Tags: mp3, ffmpeg

I have some MP3s that are in 48000 Hz sampling frequency.
I'd like to burn them to CD, so I have to reduce the sampling frequency into 441000.

How to do that using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 93):

`ffmpeg` doesn't look to be the appropriate tool; I'd normally use `sox` for audio-only files.

```
$ sox file1.mpg -r 44100 file1-enc.mpg
```

If you want to try using `ffmpeg` anyway, I think the correct command would be

```
$ ffmpeg -i file1.mpg -ar 44100 file1-enc.mpg
```

Comment: Yes sox is much better for audio, thanks for the tip!

Comment: ffmpeg supports sox resampler since 1.1

Comment: ``sox`` didn't directly work with MP3s for me. I had to install ``libsox-fmt-mp3``

Comment: `ffmpeg` is a _perfectly_ appropriate tool, though it may be overkill in a way.

Comment: And if you need constant bitrate (CBR), you can add something like `-b:a 64k` (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3).

Comment: Command to use sox resampler with the ffmpeg is `ffmpeg -i file1.mpg -af aresample=resampler=soxr -ar 44100 file1-enc.mpg`, see [FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFmpeg%20and%20the%20SoX%20Resampler).